# Bedeutung von "es packen"

Tags: meaning

Ich kenne (aus Baden-Württemberg)

> *Ich packe es jetzt*
>
> *Ich will es (gleich) packen*

als Ankündigung,  dass ich gleich los/nach Hause/ aufbrechen möchte. Dabei steht *es* allgemein für alle meine Sachen, die ich bei mir habe oder brauche (Handtasche, Jacke, etc).

Als ich jetzt aber gestern Abend zu einem Freund in Berlin gesagt habe: *Ich will es packen* wurde ich nicht verstanden.

Wenn man *will es packen* im Internet sucht, beziehen sich die Treffer auf die Bedeutung *jemand will es (=etwas, eine Herausforderung) schaffen/ bewältigen*.

Im Duden-Artikel zu [packen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/packen) gibt es auch kein passendes Beispiel zu *Ich will es packen*. Hier wird nur *der Schulranzen gepackt* oder *seine Sachen gepackt* oder *man muss noch packen* (ganz ohne Akkusativ-Objekt). Anderseits findet sich im Artikel noch *sich packen* als *sich fortscheren* (eigentlich = *sich bepacken, um fortzugehen*).

Daher meine Frage an euch:

- Kennt ihr den Ausspruch: *Ich will es packen* oder einen ähnlichen Ausdruck?
- Kommt er vielleicht nur in bestimmten Regionen vor?
- Und könnte man alternativ *Ich will mich
  packen* sagen?

Comment: Ich kenne es nicht (D-Südwest).

Comment: @chirlu also selbst für die Region BaWü keine eindeutige Antwort?

Comment: @hiergiltdiestfu: Offenbar nicht, aber BW ist auch keinesfalls einheitlich. Die Tauberbischofsheimer haben sprachlich wenig mit Freiburgern zu tun, und die wiederum wenig mit Karlsruhern oder Ulmern.

Comment: Aus dem Raum Stuttgart kenne ich vor allem `ich packe es mal`. Ob ich damit die Herausforderungen des Heimweges anpacke, oder ob ich meine Sachen packe und weiter ziehe, kann ich aber auch nciht sagen.

Comment: Mir sind In Nordbayern, alle drei Bedeutungen (heimgehen, bewältigen, Gepäck reisefertig zusammenstellen) bekannt; *es* packen würde ich aber nicht in der dritten Bedeutung verstehen, da das Objekt (Koffer, Schulranzen oder einfach *meine Sachen*) fehlt.

Comment: Ich kenne auch 'pack Dich', ich Sinne von 'hau ab!'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Raum Frankfurt/Main: Ich kenne "Pack mer's?" als Aufforderung oder Frage entsprechend "Wollen wir jetzt gehen?". Im Singular nur als "Ich pack's dann mal" usw. Die Formen "Ich packe es jetzt" oder "Ich will es (gleich) packen" habe ich noch nie gehört.

Die Webseite [redensarten-index.de](http://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=~~etwas%20packen&suchspalte[]=rart_ou) kennt die Bedeutung "aufbrechen" ebenfalls. Der Eintrag in der nächsten Zeile suggeriert, dass es vielleicht von "Koffer packen" kommt.

Comment: Nach der Antwort glaube ich, dass mein _Ich packe es jetzt_ vom Versuch kommt das umgangssprachliche _Ich pack's dann mal_ hochdeutscher klingen zu lassen. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Für die Region Dresden, sowie in Thüringen kenne ich die Wendung in der beschriebenen Bedeutung *dass ich gleich los/nach Hause/aufbrechen möchte* nicht.

In der Bedeutung *bewältigen* kenne ich es, und als aggressive Aufforderung im Rahmen von *Pack dich!* für *Schere dich fort!* auch.

*Ich will mich packen.* würde ich als *Ich will schlafen gehen.* interpretieren, aber den Sprecher in Süddeutschland verorten und es selbst nie verwenden.

Answer (score 2):

Raum Köln: Jein.

Ich kenne beispielsweise "Packen wir es an", um anzudeuten, dass wir eine Sache nun angehen. Wenn wir nun also schon vorher besprochen haben, dass wir aufbrechen wollen, *könnte* man es verwenden. Diese Vorbedingungen gegeben, habe ich "Packen wir's?" (also als Frage) durchaus schon gehört. Jedoch wird es üblicherweise bei Dingen verwendet, die anstrengend sind oder Aufwand bedeuten.

Ohne "Vorankündigung", dass man aubrechen möchte, habe ich — denke ich — es sonst noch nie gehört. Ich würde es unter Umständen verstehe, vorausgesetzt natürlich, dass es in der Situation nicht mit etwas anderem verwechselt werden kann. (Beispiel: Wir reden gerade darüber, etwas zu machen und du entscheidest dich aber nach Hause zu gehen. Dann könnte man es kontextuell auf zweierlei Arten interpretieren.)

Die drei Varianten, die du nennst ("Ich packe es", "Ich will es packen", "Ich will mich packen") klingen dennoch sehr merkwürdig. Der erste Satz geht noch so gerade.

Ich kann aus dem Stegreif gar nicht sagen, ob es eine ähnliche Phrase hier gibt. Ich sage meistens "Ich mach mich jetzt auf" oder "Ich bin dann mal", aber die kann man natürlich nicht mit deiner Phrase vergleichen.

Answer (score 1):

Für den Westen bis Südwesten des bairischen Sprachraums sowie das angrenzende Allgäu: Ja, hier wird *es packen* definitiv verstanden, in allen Zeiten.

Ich möchte aber, wie auch andere, die Deutung als *seine Sachen packen* in Frage stellen. Man würde es auch verwenden, wenn man jemanden auf der Straße trifft, sich mit der Person ein wenig verratscht, um dann festzustellen:

> Oh, ich muss es jetzt packen. Wir sehen uns morgen wieder?

Oder ähnliches. Man muss also nichts dabeihaben, insbesondere keine sieben Sachen, um es packen zu können.

Answer (score -1):

Sätze wie *ich packe es* oder *ich will es packen* sind in der Umgangssprache gängig. *Ich will mich packen* hingegen paßt nicht; das wirkt lustig, ist aber falsch. Die richtigen Varianten bedeuten in der Tat, daß man etwas Schwieriges schaffen will.

Comment: Du kennst es also gar nicht in der Bedeutung, dass man sich gleich auf den Weg machen will?

Comment: @Iris Hm, wenn ich richtig überlege, meine ich mich zu erinnern, daß ich es in der Studienzeit in Düsseldorf schon mal so gehört habe. Gibt es wohl doch.